# Как настроить Delphi 7, чтобы можно было ставить точки останова в стандартных библиотеках Delphi?

Tags: delphi, отладка, delphi-7

Каким образом настроить Delphi 7 так, чтобы возможно было ставить точки останова, скажем, в *Classes.pas*?

Текущие настройки компилятора прилагаю:

[image: Compiler]

Comment: Нужно на все исходники собрать в debug режиме (если в TPU/DCU нету отладочной информации - она там сама не появится, даже при наличии соурса), и проверить что debug опция не отключена в самом исходнике (т.е. не стоит `{$D-}` или что-то такое). Но тут сюрприз... По моему... делфи не даст пересобрать базовые библиотеки:).

Comment: Максимум что делается легко и быстро - отладка через CPU (Ctrl+Alt+C). Мне кажется лучше вам сформулировать вопрос - что вы хотите от VCL - вам ответят.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да мне просто хочется посмотреть работу некоторых функций из Classes.pas, а нет возможности :(

Comment: Вас интерисует правда одна функция? Тогда, если у вас есть "исходник" функции - вы можете на неё сделать "клон", и посмотреть работу клона (будет аналогично). До десятка клонов - приемлемая цена. Если нет - трассируйте через ассемблерный отладчик. Он не так уж сложен.

Comment: @nick_n_a, меня интересует RemoveComponent, но он много чего за собой тянет, поэтому плохо представляю себе его клонирование...

Comment: Создаём ф-цию RemoveComponent2. Копируем в неё код из исходника. И спокойно по-шагам выполняем. Проблемы могут возникнуть только если внутри ф-ции есть ссылки на приват-секцию. Но по-моему там ничего интересного:) Редактирование списка + синхронизация.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как я уже говорил, внутри RemoveComponent имеются ещё функции, соответственно про них в проекте ничего не известно. Поэтому простое копирование функции RemoveComponent не проходит :(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94163/discussion-between-unityman-and-nick-n-a).

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность отлаживать стандартные библиотеки необходимо:

1. В опциях проекта включить `Use Debug DCUs` как на картинке в вопросе, а в новых версиях Delphi ветка `Building/Delphi Compiler/Compiling`.
2. В опциях среды в `Library Path` для опции `Debug DCU path` проверить или добавить путь к скомпилированным с отладочной информацией файлам.

Если сторонние компоненты поставляются вместе с скомпилированными с отладкой исходниками (обычно папка `debug`), то прописав путь в `Debug DCU path` появится возможность также и внутри них ставить точки останова.

Для отладки единичных файлов можно воспользоваться другим простым способом. Для этого необходимо положить требуемый `.pas` файл рядом с файлом проекта и скомпилировать проект в режиме *debug*.